# tidyverse failing to load

Tags: r, tidyverse, quantmod, tidyquant

Unsure what happened, I installed tidyquant and quantmod to work with stock prices and now get the following error message

```
library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required**
```

I went through and updated all my R packages and restarted R neither of which solved the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I assume the following error code is related as well when I try and run tidyquant

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required
```

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Did you try installing `rlang` ? `install.packages('rlang')`

Comment: I saw that idea in other resolutions, getting following message

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\xxx\xxx- Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘rlang’

Comment: Have you tried restarting your R session? Make sure `install.packages("rlang")` before any other packages are loading. When you restart do you reload your previous workspace or have a start-up function in you profile that may be automatically loading the rlang package before you try to update it?

Comment: tried that same error, pixmap is loading automatically at start

Comment: Just FYI, since you solved your problem. This happened to me on two machines in the last week. I was running older versions of R on both (~v3.5). I'm guessing it may have had something to do with that. Try updating your version of R by running `installr::updateR()` from Rgui. It solved the problem for me on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

fully uninstalling tidyverse, rlang, tidyquant, and quantmod then reinstalling them while permanently uninstalling pixmap fixed the issue. Appreciate the suggestions given.